# Why would adding a delay improve data throughput in this multithreaded environment?

Tags: c++, multithreading

In my application, I have two threads, a producer (thread 1) and a consumer (thread 2). Each thread has an input and output interface (effectively a pointer to a list) that is connected to a third thread which serves as a router.

When the producer writes, it calls memcpy to copy data into a buffer and pushes the buffer into a list. Meanwhile, the router thread is round-robin searching through all the threads that are connected to it and monitoring their interfaces to see if any thread has data to send out. When it sees that thread 1's list is non-empty, it checks to determine which thread the data is intended for. The data is spliced into the destination thread's (in this case thread 2) input list, at which point thread 2 will malloc some memory, memcpy the data into it and return the pointer to this new region.

For my test, I'm measuring throughput to see how long it takes to send 100k messages of varying sizes. Thread 1 sends data of some size, thread 2 reads it and sends back a small reply message, which thread 1 reads. This would be one complete exchange. In the first test, in thread 1, I'm sending all 100k messages, and then reading 100k replies. In the second test, in thread 1, I'm alternating sending a message and waiting for the reply and repeating 100k times. In both tests, thread 2 is in a loop reading the message and sending a reply. I would expect test 1 to have higher throughput because the threads should spend less time waiting around. However, it has markedly worse throughput than test 2. I've measured how long individual function calls (to read/write) take in the two test cases and they invariably take longer in test 1 (based on the means and medians and no delay) though the numbers are of the same order of magnitude.

When I add a loop doing nothing into thread 1's sending loop in test 1, I see dramatically improved throughput for this case as opposed to not having the delay. My only guess is that adding a delay slows down the producer so the consumer can absorb the data which prevents its input list from growing very large. I'm wondering if there may be other explanations and if so, how I can test for them.

Edit

Unfortunately, my own code is just the test I described above which calls a library that actually performs the reads/writes, creates that third thread etc. It's difficult to make a minimal example out of it because the library is complex and not mine. I provide some pseudocode to illustrate the setup in more detail.

```cpp
int NUM_ITERATIONS = 100000;
int msg_reply = 2; // size of the reply message in words
int msg_size = 512; // indicates 512 64 bit words

void generate(int iterations, int size, interface* out){
    std::vector<long long> vec(size);
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        vec[i] = (long long) i;

    for(int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        out->lib_write((char*) vec.data(), size);
}

void receive(int iterations, int size, interface* in){
    for(int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        char* data = in->lib_read(size)

void producer(interface* in, interface* out){
    // test 1
    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    // write data of size msg_size, NUM_ITERATIONS times to out
    generate(NUM_ITERATIONS, msg_size, out);
    // read data of size msg_reply, NUM_ITERATIONS times from in
    receive(NUM_ITERATIONS, msg_reply, in);
    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    // using NUM_ITERATIONS, msg_size and time, compute and print throughput to stdout
    print_throughput(end-start, "throughput_0", msg_size);

    // test 2
    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(int j = 0; j < NUM_ITERATIONS; j++){
        generate(1, msg_size, out);
        receive(1, msg_reply, in);
    }
    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    print_throughput(end-start, "throughput_1", msg_size);
}

void consumer(interface* in, interface* out){
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++}{
        for(int j = 0; j < NUM_ITERATIONS; j++){
            receive(1, msg_size, in);
            generate(1, msg_reply, out);
        }
    }
}
```

The calls to `lib_write()` and `lib_read()` become fairly complex. To elaborate on the description above, the data gets memcpy'd into a buffer and then moved into a list. The interface has a condition variable member and the write calls its `notify_one()` method. The third thread is looping through all the interface pointers it has and checking to see if their lists are non-empty. If so, the data is spliced from one output list to the destination's input list using the `splice()` method in std::list. Meanwhile, the consumer calls the `lib_read()` which waits on the condition variable while the interface is empty, and then memcpy's the data into a new region and returns it.

```cpp
// note: these will not compile as is. Undefined variables are class members

char * interface::lib_read(size_t * _size){

    char * ret;
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
        // packets is an std::list containing the incoming data
        while (packets.empty()) {
            cv.wait(lock);
        }
        curr_read_it = packets.begin();
    }

    size_t buff_size = curr_read_it->size;

    ret = (char *)malloc(buff_size);
    memcpy((char *)ret, (char *)curr_read_it->data, buff_size);
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
        packets.erase(curr_read_it);
        curr_read_it = packets.end();
    }
    return ret;
}

void interface::lib_write(char * data, int size){
    // indicates the destination thread id
    long long header = 1;

    // buffer is a just an array that's max packet sized
    memcpy((char *)buffer.data, &header, sizeof(long long));
    memcpy((char *)buffer.data + sizeof(long long), (char *)data, size * sizeof(long long));

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mutex);
    packets.push_back(std::move(buffer));
    cv.notify_one();
}

// this is on thread 3
void route(){
    do{
        // this is a vector containing all the "out" interfaces
        for(int i = 0; i < out_ptrs.size(); i++){
            interface <long long> * _out = out_ptrs[i];
            if(!_out->empty()){
                // this just returns the header id (also locks the mutex)
                long long dest= _out->get_dest();
                // looks up the correct interface based on the id and splices
                // a packet into from _out to the appropriate one. Locks mutex
                in_ptrs[dest_map[dest]]->splice(_out);   
            }
        }

    }while(!done());
```

Comment: Please provide some actual code - ideally a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: There's no guarantee that a context switch will occur when a mutex/lock is released.  Hence I suspect that in your first test thread 1 is 'hogging' the lock and sending large chunks of the 100k messages before thread 2 gets a chance to acquire the lock and read/reply to those messages -- the worst case scenario being that thread 1 sends all 100k messages before thread 2 acquires the lock and begins to process them.  As per the comment above though we really need to see some code.

Comment: "*third thread which serves as a router*" is an immediate red flag... need to see the code.

Comment: I've updated the question with some code. It's not reproducible as is because the library in question becomes fairly complex. I don't necessarily need to fix this problem at this point. Identifying the causes is sufficient so my question is more general about what impact the introduction of delays could have in a multithreaded environment and how to test for them.

Comment: "Here's 10% of my code, where's the problem?" 9 chances out of 10 it's in other 90%. "I added a delay and my code now runs faster". Then there's definitely a bug. "Is adding a delay a valid method of mitigating a bug?" Not in our sandbox.Not being able to see the rest of the code I would guess the problem is the unlimited packets queue. Try adding a limit, and another condvar and a mutex to signal that it's not full.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for general advice on what factors may influence multithreading performance and what to test for in order to better understand what was going on.

I talked to some other people and the advice I got that was helpful was to determine if the OS scheduling was the issue (which is what I suspected but was unsure how to test). Essentially, I used `taskset` and `sched_affinity()` to force the application to run on one core or on a subset of cores and looked at how they compared to each other and to the unrestricted case.

Based on the restrictions, I got dramatically different results and could see some trends so I'm pretty confident in saying that it's an OS scheduling issue. Different ones can yield better performance under different workloads.